# How to verify email and name on a server using FB access token received by javascript SDK on a client side

Tags: facebook, authentication, server, facebook-access-token, verification

I have a client (HTML+JavaScript) and a server (ASP MVC) and I need to provide a user some private information. To achieve that I need to verify that

1. user authenticated and
2. use users email address to retrieve its
       private information.

I want to use FB authentication. It looks pretty straight forward but has a flaw which I am sure people can tell me how to solve or what am I missing.

1. client initializes FB SDK and requests user to authenticate using FB
2. result of successful step #1 is access token.
3. We can place another call to FB using this access token to retrieve
   email and name.

How can my server know what is the email and name of the authenticated user?
My understanding that client should not send email and name to the server (*it can be hacked and can not be trusted*) but instead client should send the received access token, which server should use to get user's email and name, but on the server side.
Please explain, give me an example, point me to a link on how can I achieve that on the server as all my searches for that failed.
One more time, my backend is ASP MVC.

Comment: I guess I was confused with what I need to do in ASP MVC in order to get a user info having an access token.
The suggested link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api helped me to understand that all I really need is to make a HTTPS GET call (from the server) to "graph.facebook.com" passing access cookie (received from the client) to retrieve the information I need and exclude a possibility of hijacked/compromised client passing me a wrong email.
Using GRAPH API means placing https calls to GRAPH.facebook.com - that was no clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, make a call to the Graph API:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email`

Use the Access Token and you will get the correct data:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email&access_token=xxx`

Btw, you should also read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Comment: Could you give me an example or link to where I can find an example?

Comment: there is example code in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: Thanks! "Using the Graph API" is what I needed.

Comment: accepting an answer should always be possible, afaik. i will add the long version of the api call to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was confused with what I need to do in ASP MVC in order to get a user info having an access token.
The suggested link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api helped me to understand that all I really need is to make a HTTPS GET call (from the server) to "graph.facebook.com" passing access cookie (received from the client) to retrieve the information I need and exclude a possibility of hijacked/compromised client passing me a wrong email.
Using GRAPH API means placing https calls to GRAPH.facebook.com - that was no clear to me.